# Wordpress -- Allow HTML tags in wp editor

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wordpress site and I am trying to add the following into a page, using the text editor on the wp-admin:

```
<a target="divtarget" id="link"> 
<!---
   ...
 -->
</a>
```

The problem is, whenever I edit it, it shows on the site. Then when I go back, edit it again, it is no longer there. I can't seem to figure out why, I assume that it's because HTML tags are not supported in the visual mode.

Is there a way to disable this so the tags are enabled and I can edit them?

Answer (score 4):

As I said, raw `html` input is only possible if you turn the `visual mode` off in the Wordpress Editor.
Have a look at this example:

[image: Wordpress Editor]

This way you can easily switch between the two modes.
To permanently turn off the visual mode you have to do this:

```
Users -> Authors & Profile

Find your username and click on Edit.

Uncheck "Visual Editor"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I think it's ok. To edit HTML tags, you must switch from visual mode to text mode. The visual editor is something like MS Word. You can't even paste HTML in it to make it rendered.

When you paste HTML in visual mode, the code is shown on the page bacuase wordpress encodes HTML from the visual mode with `htmlspecialchars()`. In text mode, wordpress dosen't encode your code.

For the PHP reference for this look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php

If you only want to write in text mode you can turn off visual mode in your wordpress userprofile.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @Harray Thank you for editing. I forgot to check the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hook if some tags can't be visible in your editor.

https://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/201762/add-html-tags-to-the-allowed-tags-list-in-wordpress